# How to pass parameter in preg_replace to a function in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to do something like this:

I have this string:

```
Lorem ipsum {shortcode 42} dolor sit amet.
```

I want to parse it like this:

```php
preg_replace('/\{shortcode (\d+)\}/i', MyClass::myFunction('$1') , $content);
```

The `MyClass` code looks like this:

```php
class MyClass {
    public static function myFunction(string $id) {
        // ...

        return 'hello world';
    }

}
```

But in the `myFunction()` the `$id` will always the `$1` string, and not the content of the original `$1`, what is a number.

How can I pass the preg_replace replacement value in parameter to my function?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: _“But in the myFunction() the $id will always the $1 string”_ - not only that, it will be _called_ before any replacing even happens. If you specify a function _call_ as parameter of another function, then that function call happens before the other function even runs.

Comment: I checked this too, but same result. Could you present me an example with my code? I think this is a too simple thing, but I don't see something basic thing... Thanks!

Comment: There are multiple examples on that manual page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without rewriting your class method, use an anonymous function in `preg_replace_callback` to call your method using index `1` as the first capture group match:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/\{shortcode (\d+)\}/i',
                                function($m) {
                                    return MyClass::myFunction($m[1]);
                                }, $content);
```

Or you can call the static method, but then you would need to use the `1` index of the argument there:

```
// ['MyClass', 'myFunction'] or 'MyClass::myFunction'
$result = preg_replace('/\{shortcode (\d+)\}/i', ['MyClass', 'myFunction'], $content);

class MyClass {
    public static function myFunction(array $array) {
        // use $array[1]

        return 'hello world';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example with static method of class as a callback:

```
class MyClass {
    static function myFunction($arg) {
        return "[Hello, {$arg[1]}]";
    }
}

$content = 'Lorem ipsum {shortcode 42} dolor sit amet.';
echo preg_replace_callback('/\{shortcode (\d+)\}/i', 'MyClass::myFunction', $content);
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/SjkDu).